# using move semantincs in parameterized constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, move

I've a class which has among other, an attribute consisting of `std::vector<std::vector<T> >`. In the parameterized constructor, I'm using move-semantics.
When I create an object of this class, I'm getting a compiler error associated with the `constructor`. Does anybody has an idea if the initialization was properly done using move-semantics? Or is it actually related to the `vector<vector>` itself?

```
template < class T, class L = size_t >
class Foo{
  public:
     ...
     Foo(std::vector<L> , std::vector<std::vector<T> > );
     ...
  private:
     ...
     std::vector<L> shape_; 
     std::vector<std::vector<T> > cost_;
     ...
```

};

```
template < class T, class L >
Foo<T,L>::Foo( std::vector<L> shape, std::vector< std::vector< T > > ucosts )
:shape_(std::move(shape)), cost_(std::move(ucosts))
{

}
```

And here's the way how I initialize the object:

```
typedef double termType;
typedef Foo<termType, int> myFoo;
std::vector<int> ushape(10);
std::vector< std::vector< termType> > ucosts(2, std::vector<termType> ( 5, 0 ) );
myFoo ff1(ushape, ucosts); // <------ DOES NOT WORK
Foo<termType, int> ff2(ushape, ucosts); // <------ DOES WORK
```

The compiler message error is: `error C2664:

```
'Foo<T,L>::Foo(std::vector<_Ty>,std::vector<std::vector<double>>)' : cannot convert
 parameter 2 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty>'
 1>          with
 1>          [
 1>              T=termType,
 1>              L=int,
 1>              _Ty=int
 1>          ]
 1>          and
 1>          [
 1>              _Ty=std::vector<float>
 1>          ]
 1>          and
 1>          [
 1>              _Ty=std::vector<double>
 1>          ]
 1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Comment: And if you try `Foo<double,int> ff(costs)` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig, the bug still persists. Any ideas?

Comment: if you changed it the same error can't possibly exist, as there is no mention of `float` anywhere in your code at all once that change is actually done. [It works if all the types align correctly](http://ideone.com/2G16xx), so I've no idea what your problem is. Once the code is *valid* (i.e. syntax errors removed), it *works*.

Answer (score 1):

`termType` is `double`, but `Foo`'s template argument is `float`. This means that in the ctor, you're trying to move a `std::vector<double>` into a `std::vector<float>`, which is of course impossible.

**EDIT :**
Actually, the error happens even before the move - you're trying to *pass* a `std::vector<double>` as an argument for a `std::vector<float>` parameter, and that's not possible either.

Comment: @ Angew, I did actually an error when I was writing the post (both types are `double`). I edited it and actually the problem still exists.

Comment: @Tin The error message is clearly saying it cannot convert from `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` to `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`. Also, it's mentioning a two-parameter constructor of `Foo`. Are you showing the relevant code in the question?

Comment: @ Angew, updated it now. Do you mind explaining why there's a problem when creating object `ff1` and not `ff2`?

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/rj3bkI). Either your compiler is broken, or you're again not showing your actual code. Probably the latter, since it's missing a right paren in `ucosts` definition. Please provide a minimal example which reproduces the error and post it *verbatim.* So that it can be just copied & pasted to e.g. ideone.